# Sencha Touch 2 store is loaded multiple time [Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm having a weird problem with the Sencha Touch 2 Store class. Here is what I have:

- A simple view **PollsList** that defines a list view (with a store attribute set to **Polls**). I've included the required store as follow: `requires:['Polls']`,
- A store class **Polls** with a model attribute set to **Poll** and a dummy data attribute,
- A model class named **Poll** (the simplest possible),
- An app.js file with the following launch methode:

`var pollsListView = Ext.create('PollsList');`

`Ext.Viewport.add(pollsListView);`

`Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(pollsListView);`

I've also included the `stores: ['Polls']` declaration in the app.js as required.

Now, the weird thing is when I access the **PollsList** view, the **Poll** store is being loaded indefinitely, till I got a the following error:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded sencha-touch.js:598`

And the stack seems to loop on the following calls:

`Ext.ClassManager.instantiate sencha-touch.js:6378`

`(anonymous function) sencha-touch.js:3198`

`(anonymous function) app/store/Polls.js:4`

`Ext.apply.globalEval sencha-touch.js:598`

`Ext.apply.globalEval sencha-touch.js:599`

`Ext.apply.loadScriptFile sencha-touch.js:7673`

`Ext.apply.require sencha-touch.js:7831`

`Ext.apply.syncRequire sencha-touch.js:7695`

`(anonymous function)`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems weird, done many a times, but did not went wrong.

Any ways, try removing the **setActiveItem** as there is only one view and it will take it as active.

Remove the **require** line from the code, as it seems that currently it is not required though.(Just because i want to make this sample running).

Now, try initializing the store, as

```
var store = Ext.create("YourStore")   // 
var listControl = Ext.craeate("YourList" ,{store : "aboveCreatedStore" , ..... });
listControl.setData( {name :'hello'} ); // hoping the model is having one String type field
Ext.ViewPort.add(listControl);
```

Thats it...

The above given code is not a complete solution(its like a patch), but it is to make you know what wrong you are doing in your current code.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem with your solution. I suspect the problem is coming from the Store itself. Coz' when I comment all the **requires** attributes from the app.js and PollsList.js, I still have this problem (using your solution of course).

Comment: I found my mistake.

Instead of defining, in my store file, my store like so:
`Ext.define('MyStore', { ... });`


It was defined like so: `Ext.create('MyStore', { ... });`

And somehow, when requiring this store, It got instantiated indefinitely 

**Anyway, problem solved!**